# Traversing the DOM with HTML Agility Pack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I'm having trouble figuring out how to traverse the DOM with HTML Agility Pack.

For example let's say that I wanted to find an element with `id="gbqfsa"`.

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(Url);
            var foo = from bar in doc.DocumentNode.DescendantNodes()
                          where bar.Attributes["id"].Value == "gbqfsa"
                          select bar.InnerText;
```

Right now I'm doing this (above), but `foo` is coming out as `null`.  What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** This is the `if` statement I was using.  I was just testing to see if the elements `InnerText` equaled "Google Search."

```
if (foo.Equals("Google Search"))
            {
                HasSucceeded = 1;
                MessageBox.Show(yay);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("kms");
            }
            return HasSucceeded;
```

Comment: `foo` cannot be `null` if the line var `foo = ...` is executed. It can be an empty collection but not `null`.

Comment: Okay well when I step through the code it says it's null.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong though?

Comment: Could you give an example of URL and element id that doesn't work?

Comment: http://google.com, id="gbqfsa"

Comment: I don't have any issue with this. Have you tested the answer from @DanGarant?

Comment: Not yet, I'm kinda jumping between two stack overflow questions haha.  I'll update soon.

Comment: Yeah I tested the answer from @DanGarant to no avail.  Still not finding the element.

Comment: It doesn't find the element, but is `foo == null`? And you wrote `doc.LoadHtml(Url)`. What is exactly `Url`?

Comment: **Foo is not null.**  I just did a simple `if` test and it's not, I was wrong.  The Url is exactly http://google.com

Comment: Maybe my `if` statement is wrong... adding it right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do is:

```
var foo = (from bar in doc.DocumentNode.DescendantNodes()
          where bar.GetAttributeValue("id", null) == "gbqfsa"
          select bar.InnerText).FirstOrDefault();
```

You forgot `FirstOrDefault()` to select the first element that satisfy the condition in `where`.

And I replace `Attributes["id"].Value` by `GetAttributeValue("id", null)` not to throw an exception if an element does have an `id` attribute.

Comment: On a quick side note, how in my `if` statement can I just test if an element exists?

Comment: if no element exists, `foo == null` (thanks to [FirstOrDefault()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault.aspx))

Comment: Yeah `foo == null` is coming out as `true`.  Whatever ill just figure it out.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `foo` is coming out as `null`. More likely, `bar.Attributes["id"]` is null for some of the elements in the tree since not all descendant nodes have an "id" property. I would recommend using the `GetAttributeValue` method, which will return a default value if the attribute is not found.

```
var foo = from bar in doc.DocumentNode.DescendantNodes()
            where bar.GetAttributeValue("id", null) == "gbqfsa"
            select bar.InnerText;
```